# UWP C# - Databinding and Updating of Controls

Tags: c#, uwp

Let me preface this by saying I'm writing my first UWP app.  This app will pull some JSON values from servers and aggregate the results.  I'd like to give users the ability to add and remove servers.  I'm storing the info in the application data folder using the LocalObjectStorageHelper from the Community Tookkit.  Here is the class that handles that:

```
class ServerSettingsStore
{

    LocalObjectStorageHelper helper = new LocalObjectStorageHelper();
    private string serverNumber;

    public ServerSettingsStore(string serverNum)
    {
        serverNumber = serverNum;

    }

    public void Save_Settings(ServerInfo serverInfo)
    {

        helper.Save(serverNumber, serverInfo);

    }

    public ServerInfo Retrive_Settings()
    {
        var result = helper.Read<ServerInfo>(serverNumber);

        return result;

    }
```

Here is the class that handles the ServerInfo:

```
 public class ServerInfo
{

    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string ServerAddress { get; set; }
    public string ServerAuthKey { get; set; }


    public string HostNameSummary
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ServerName;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, on the UWP Page, I'm binding Data to a list box successfully:

XAML Code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ServerList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ServerList, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionChanged="ServerList_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ServerInfo">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ServerName}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ServerAddress}"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class ListViewModel
{

    private ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> serverlist = new ObservableCollection<ServerInfo>();
    public ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> ServerList { get { return this.serverlist; } }

    public ListViewModel()
    {

        for (var i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(new ServerCount().NumberOfServers); i++)
        {
            var settingsstore = new SettingsStore(i.ToString());
            var serverinfo = new ServerInfo();
            serverinfo = settingsstore.Retrive_Settings();
            this.serverlist.Add(new ServerInfo() { ServerName = serverinfo.ServerName, ServerAddress = serverinfo.ServerAddress, ServerAuthKey = serverinfo.ServerAuthKey });

        }
        
    }

}
```

Now comes the challenge.  I have a SplitView panel that allows a user to modify the Server Name and IP Address, and saves it back the OjectStorageHelper.  All of that works, but the data binding of the listview does not get updated with the new values.  What is the best way to refresh this information? Am I breaking the data out into too many classes?

Comment: So once something is written to the ObjectStorageHelper, you want the listview to be updated? if so, can you show the that is writing to the ObjectStorageHelper? Is it in the same view model as the one above?

Comment: The class that writes to ObjectStorageHelper is in a different view model than what builds the ListBox.  Should I combine them into the same class?

Comment: If you do, then once something is saved to the ObjectStorageHelper, you can also add that item to the ObservableCollection and that would get the ListView to show it.

Comment: The main point is that once something is saved to the ObjectStorageHelper, you will need to add it to the ObservableCollection. So if you keep them in separate classes, make sure you can still sync them somehow, maybe through events/notifications but that depends on how your code is structured.

Comment: That makes sense.  I think I have some ideas on how to restructure things to bring them together.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems like when you are writing to the `ObjectStorageHelper` you aren't adding the new item(s) to the `ObservableCollection` property so your `ListView` is not updating as expected.

You will need to add that item to the collection once the save/write operation is successful and your `ListView` will update properly (your x:bind in the xaml fragment you shared looks ok).

Now, it seems like the code that works with ObjectStorageHelper is in a different ViewModel. I don't know how your code is structured, but you can either bring that code into the same ViewModel above and then update the ObservableCollection or possibly use Events/Notifications that are fired when the save operation is completed successfully and then a handler will add the item to the collection.

Comment: That’s exactly my problem.  I’ll restructure some code and try it out.  Thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that @Pusta